# Adding new variables to existing data that correlate with one or two existing ones

Tags: r, tidyverse, correlation

How can I add two more variables with the following conditions?

1. Variable "c" that has a 0.7 correlation with variable "a".
2. If possible, variable "d" that correlates simultaneously with "a" and "b".

**Simulated data**

```
n = 100

d = tibble(a = rnorm(n, 50, 20),
           b = rnorm(n, 10, 0.4))

d
```

[image]

*Tidyverse solutions are much appreciated!*

Comment: Its not clear to me what you mean by "simultaneously correlated with a and b" - see my answer below for first part of your question

Comment: Indeed. The first part is not clear too, because you don't specify "c". The solution will be different if it comes from a normal distribution or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small function that take a vector `x` and a desired `rho` and returns a vector such that `cor(<vector>,x) ==` rho`).

```
f <- function(x,rho) {
  orth = lm(runif(length(x))~x)$residuals
  rho*sd(orth)*x + orth*sd(x)*sqrt(1-rho^2)
}
```

Now we apply the function to column `a` to create a column `c` such that `cor(a,c) == 0.7`

```
d %>%  mutate(c = f(a,.7))
```

Answer (score 1):

The second is actually more easier (for me at least): just make z-scores out of both a and b and add or average them. It will correlate with both a and b with 0.7

```
d <- d %>% 
  mutate(d=((a - mean(a)) / sd(a)) +
           ((b- mean(b)) / sd(b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Iman and Conover method (1982) developed in the mc2d package (a **rank** correlation structure).

```
library(mc2d)
cc <- rnorm(n,50,20)
cc <- cornode(cbind(d$a,cc), target=0.7)[,"cc"]
d$c <- cc
cor(d)
```

For more than one variable, you have to build a matrix of correlation.

```
## Target
(corrTarget <- matrix(c(1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1), ncol=3))

dd <- rnorm(n,50,20)
dd <- cornode(cbind(a=d$a,b=d$b,dd), target=corrTarget)
cor(dd)
d$b <- dd[,"b"]
d$d <- dd[,"dd"]

cor(d)
```

The final correlation structure should be checked because it is not always possible to build the target correlation structure.